# How to decide which matching score is best or worst in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-aggregation, elasticsearch-dsl

I am currently running search based based name, address, city, state and zip code on Elasticsearch index. I am getting some best matches and some worst also.

Name, address, city , state and zip code is different column and same way indexed into Elasticsearch, I have added index mapping.

Requirement: I have to decide a baseline score, which will be used to accept or decline matching results.

```
{
    "properties": {
        "id": {
            "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "address": {
            "type": "text"
        },
        "city": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
        },
        "state": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
        },
        "zip_code": {
            "type": "keyword",
            "normalizer": "lowercase"
        }
   }
}
```

Any help here is really appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: baseline to what though?

Comment: take a look function score [link](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html)

Comment: my requirement is I just want to have one value which will be used to decide whether to accept or reject search result.
E.g. If i decide 15 as baseline, if my match score is >=15 then I will accept search or reject in case my match score is less than 15.